# Do upper case letters take up more memory?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a file system that will handle lots of searching through the directories. Would it make a difference if I used upper or lower case letters in terms of memory usage on the folder names?

Answer (score 10):

Case does not affect the size of a character.  Some characters take up different sizes in certain character encodings, but generally letters from the same language all have the same size.

Comment: That's going to depend on the encoding that you use, and the characters you have in that encoding.  Not all encodings are fixed size.

Comment: That is correct, but the OP asked about the difference between upper and lower case.  I don't know of any encoding that has a size difference between cases in a single language---normally the difference will be to handle "extended" character sets with longer characters.

Comment: But you don't say that the upper/lower case version of each character within a charset won't be different sizes, you said all characters all take up the same amount of memory, which is very wrong.

Comment: I thought the context made the answer clear.  But I'll reword it to clarify

Answer (score 5):

No. Each character takes up the same amount of memory.

You can get into some technicalities with character sets and encoding, but unless you've got a really obscure one, uppercase and lowercase use the same number of bits.

Answer (score 1):

No. Especially assuming that you're only using ascii characters.

Answer (score 1):

No. Both are of type `char` which is defined in C# as 16-bit long numeric value. More reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A data type `char` must have at least big enough to contain an encoding of at least the 95 different characters which make up the basic execution character set.

This equals a minimum of 8 bits, or one byte. Meaning `a` or `A` in a variable `char` will at least require 1 byte. So no, it's the same.